# Gitlab-ce 500 error in project after backup restore

Tags: git, gitlab

after restore the backup in my new gitlab-ce server in a very old project i always get a 500 error in the web page.

LOGS:

> ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
>       Started GET "/root/licenciamiento-ss" for 84.126.154.63 at 2016-09-22 17:17:36 +0000
>       Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
>         Parameters: {"namespace_id"=>"root", "id"=>"licenciamiento-ss"}
>       Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 402ms (ActiveRecord: 19.3ms)

> OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError (bad decrypt):
>         app/models/project.rb:497:in `import_url'
>         app/models/project.rb:533:in`external_import?'
>         app/models/project.rb:525:in `import?'
>         app/models/project.rb:541:in`import_in_progress?'
>         app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:94:in `show'
>         lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:15:in`call'
>         lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:16:in `call'

> ==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
>       2016-09-22_17:17:36.88358 2016/09/22 17:17:36 ErrorPage: serving predefined error page: 500
>       2016-09-22_17:17:36.88686 vps2.inforfenix.com:8888 @ - - [2016-09-22 17:17:36.3505033 +0000 UTC] "GET /root/licenciamiento-ss HTTP/1.1" 500 2408 "http://vps2.inforfenix.com:8888/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36" 0.536080

> ==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
>       84.126.154.63 - - [22/Sep/2016:17:17:36 +0000] "GET /root/licenciamiento-ss HTTP/1.1" 500 2408 "http://vps2.inforfenix.com:8888/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current <==
2016-09-22_17:17:37.12826 2016/09/22 17:17:37 Send static file "/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public/favicon.ico" ("") for GET "/favicon.ico"
2016-09-22_17:17:37.13234 vps2.inforfenix.com:8888 @ - - [2016-09-22 17:17:37.127819932 +0000 UTC] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "http://vps2.inforfenix.com:8888/root/licenciamiento-ss" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36" 0.004461

==> /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log <==
84.126.154.63 - - [22/Sep/2016:17:17:37 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 5430 "http://vps2.inforfenix.com:8888/root/licenciamiento-ss" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36"
```

After the backup restore I can access normally practically all the repos but the 3 more old are unusable

Comment: Does a simple `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy db_key_base in /etc/gitlab/gitlab-secrets.json from the old instance to the new one.

Then run:

```
sudo gitlab-rails runner "Project.where.not(import_url: nil).each { |p| p.import_data.destroy if p.import_data }"
```